# one PC with two screens

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have connected my computer with 2 screens  .
Is there any way to enable me to work on these screens each one alone on the same PC.

Like...; one of them will work as monitoring and the other one will work for my mails and move between screens by the same mouse ..

Any ideas ... Please help

Comment: When you connect two screens that should be the default behavior. If something is not working the configuration depends on the OS. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: More info please. How are they not working currently ? What operating system ? One graphics card ? etc etc.

Comment: seems like you are currently using duplicate displays all you need to do is to extend your secondary/second monitor. Try the following link for a pictures and a how-to do it: http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-11319_7-5620889-6.html (Note: I'm assuming that you are using windows as your operating system)

Answer (score 6):

This is assuming you have windows XP. Right click your desktop, click properties, navigate to the settings tab, select the secondary monitor(which ever one you don't want to be the main monitor), and tick the "extend my desktop to this monitor box". If you have 7 or Vista right click the desktop, go to screen resolution and follow my other steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, this configuration generally is easier to set up with the video card manufacturer (Nvidia, AMD, Intel) configuration application, as they provide two ways of using your display:

1. Extend the desktop in any direction (using monitors side to side or one on top of the other) including the task bar and the wallpaper.
2. Extend the desktop workspace, keeping the task bar in the first display.

Either way will give you the possibility of having more workspace.

You can edit the way the virtual display is oriented relative to the monitors in physical space in the Display Properties.